# Shrink database in small chunks

Tags: sql-server

I have a database of 3TB. I need to perform shrinking in the test environment before doing on production database.  I read some blogs they say to do in small chunks.

How to do in small chunks?

Comment: Why are you shrinking it? How much free space is there to reclaim?

Comment: We are thinking to get it down by around 750000 mb. Is it possible to bring that much from 3.75 tb. How much can we reclaim? Any estimates

Comment: Generally speaking shrinking is a bad idea. If the database has used 3TB, which is small overall, it will probably use 3TB again. If you are having performance issues and thinking smaller means faster shrinking the the database is not going to make it faster.

Comment: Estimates? You can simply have the database tell you how much space is actually in use. It can't shrink below that. Check "space available" under "properties". It's impossible to shrink by more than that.

Answer (score 1):

In management studio you can tell shrink command new size. So basically you set smaller size every time you run shrink.
I don't know SQL command for doing it. But as usual in SQL-Server you can generate one for yourself.
OK just googled it. Following shrinks DB UserDB and leaves it with 10% of free space.

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (UserDB, 10);
GO
```

MS reference to [SHRINKDATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-database)